# Display html/css web page in C# Application?

Tags: c#, html, css, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I am currently developing an application for my website (file downloader/updater) and I would like to create a block within my application that reads and displays a html web page from my website within the C# application.

This html/css page would be very simple (recent change log or dev blog).

How can I red and display the html page within my C# application?

For example, I want the html page content to be displayed in the blank space in this application http://puu.sh/5BFcv.png

Answer (score 2):

If you're developing for Winforms/WPF, you should be able to use the standard `WebBrowser` control to display HTML. Although it's powered on IE7+ I believe, you stated that you only need to display a bit of data, so it'll probably work out fine.

Or you can take a look at the [HTML Renderer](http://htmlrenderer.codeplex.com/) project on Codeplex and use that if the default `WebBrowser` control doesn't work out for you (broken pages).

Also, a side note: For something as simple as a changelog delivering mechanism, I'd personally avoid using a Webbrowser to display HTML. Why not retrieve the changelog in plain text format and populate the information natively.

Sample code you can use to download a text file from a web server and set it as a label's text:

```
    public void Main()
    {
        using (WebRequest req = new WebRequest())
        {
            string downloadedChangelog = req.DownloadString(new Uri("http://www.site.com/changelog.txt"));
            changelogLabel.Text = downloadedChangelog;      
        }
    }
```

Or, if you want to make the downloading string part asynchronous (won't freeze the UI), you can do this:

```
    public void Main()
    {
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.DownloadStringCompleted += client_DownloadStringCompleted;
            client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.google.com"));
        }
    }

    private void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        changelogLabel.Text = e.Result.ToString();
    }
```

Make sure to put a `using System.Net;` statement at the top of your code, or type it all out.

Comment: How would you go about retrieving it in plain text and displaying it within the application? (I am pretty noob to C# development and have only taken some basic courses in college for C#, nothing as extensive as this).

Comment: You can use the `HttpWebRequest` or `WebClient` class to fetch a page's source and store it in a string. Then, you can change a `Label`'s text to the downloaded string!

Comment: Say I have a changelog.txt file located on my web server, how could I go about reading that file and displaying it line by line within my application?

Comment: Formatting is messed up, I'll edit my original answer for the sample code

Comment: nevermind, figured out the error. I needed to make a call to form1 since the method is staic and the field I am calling is not. via Form1 form1 = new Form1();

Comment: I made a mistake there, you should remove the `static` keyword in the method header, since all winforms controls should be non-static as well. Sorry about that

Comment: ok, so using the newly updated code, with the exception of changeloglabel.Text being replaced with txtChangeLog.Text, when I run my app, the text box contains no content. The text file it is reading from is found at http://www.survivaloperations.net/v2/changelog.txt do i need to add client_DownloadStringCompleted(); in the code somewhere to have it add the text to the box?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42472/discussion-between-andrew-and-meta)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a WebBrowser controls to your app.